# Android Application in Dotnet

Tags: c#, android, .net

I would like to develop Android applications using the .Net platform.

Could you please give me list of the available SDKs or website URLs for Android development with C#.

Comment: please google it first... haven't you heared of xamarin?? http://xamarin.com/android

Comment: Note that searching for links to tools/libraries is off-topic on SO. Please use search engines like http://google.com, http://bing.com or even SO own search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+android before asking question as there is small chance that you are not the first person trying to solve particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Mono for Android which allows you to develop in C#

http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid